# ASP button ID not being find "findbyelementID" in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, getelementbyid

Trying to find Id of a ASP.Net control in JavaScript but it says ID not found, **I looked at different other related question but they are all in a ASP form or alike, however here I am using DIV tags**, and its giving me error on page,

Code :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphSubmit" runat="server">
<div id="divConfMessage" style="BORDER-RIGHT:black thin solid; BORDER-TOP:black thin solid; DISPLAY:none; Z-INDEX:200; BORDER-LEFT:black thin solid; BORDER-BOTTOM:black thin solid; background-color:white;">
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: white;TEXT-ALIGN: center" id="confirmText"></div>
    <div style="Z-INDEX: 105;HEIGHT: 22%;BACKGROUND-COLOR: white;TEXT-ALIGN: center"></div>
    <div style="Z-INDEX: 105;BACKGROUND-COLOR: white;TEXT-ALIGN: center">
        <asp:Button ID="btnConfOK"  Width="200px" Height="25px" CssClass="gradientbutton" OnClick="btDelete_Click" Runat="server" Text="Yes"></asp:Button>
        <asp:Button ID="btnConfCancel" Width="200px" Height="25px" CssClass="gradientbutton" Runat="server" Text="No"></asp:Button>
    </div>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="CustomDialog.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        function ShowMessage()
        {
            DisplayConfirmMessage('Do you really want to delete this decision?',480,120);
            document.getElementById('<%=btnConfOK.ClientID%>').focus();
            //SetDefaultButton('btnConfOK');
            return false;
        }
 </script>
    <asp:Button ID="btDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="gradientbutton"
    UseSubmitBehavior="False"
    OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Please Wait...';ShowMessage();"
    Text="Delete" Width="200px"  />
```

EDIT:

**I made the changes and the Dialog box comes up and disappears then :|, I think I need to add the control to DOM but got no clue how i gonna do that in this context :|**

here's the tutorial link i followed
[Dialog box tutorial](http://aspalliance.com/1366_Building_a_Custom_Confirmation_Dialog_Box.all)

js script

```
var divWidth = '';
var divHeight = '';
var txtFirstButton = 'OK';
var txtSecondButton = 'Cancel'
    function DisplayConfirmMessage(msg,width,height)
    {
            // Set default dialogbox width if null
            if(width == null)
            divWidth = 180 
            else 
            divWidth = width;

            // Set default dialogBox height if null
            if(height == null)
            divHeight = 90 
            else 
            divHeight = height;


            // Ge the dialogbox object
            var divLayer = document.getElementById('divConfMessage');
            // Set dialogbox height and width
            SetHeightWidth(divLayer)
            // Set dialogbox top and left
            SetTopLeft(divLayer);

            // Show the div layer
            divLayer.style.display = 'block';
            // Change the location and reset the width and height if window is resized
            window.onresize = function() { if(divLayer.style.display == 'block'){ SetTopLeft(divLayer); SetHeightWidth(divLayer)}}
            // Set the dialogbox display message
            document.getElementById('confirmText').innerHTML = msg;
    }

    function SetTopLeft(divLayer)
    {
        // Get the dialogbox height
        var divHeightPer = divLayer.style.height.split('px')[0];

         // Set the top variable 
        var top = (parseInt(document.body.offsetHeight)/ 2) - (divHeightPer/2)
        // Get the dialog box width
        var divWidthPix = divLayer.style.width.split('px')[0];

        // Get the left variable
        var left = (parseInt(document.body.offsetWidth)/2) - (parseInt(divWidthPix)/2);
        // set the dialogbox position to abosulute
        divLayer.style.position = 'absolute';

        // Set the div top to the height 
        divLayer.style.top = top

        // Set the div Left to the height 
        divLayer.style.left = left;
    }
    function SetHeightWidth(divLayer)
    {
        // Set the dialogbox width
        divLayer.style.width = divWidth + 'px';
        // Set the dialogbox Height
        divLayer.style.height = divHeight + 'px'
    }

    function SetDefaultButton(defaultButton)
    {
            // Set the focus on the Cancel button
            document.getElementById(defaultButton).focus();
    }
```

**If I remove "UseSubmitBehavior="False", It works fine, except when I click on Yes, it doesn't closes the Dialog box**

Comment: trace it and see what id it tries to call

Comment: Dunno why i got negative comment for it :/

Answer (score 4):

getElementById takes a string, so you need to quote the id, like this:

```
document.getElementById('<%=btnConfOK.ClientID%>').focus();
```

Comment: sorry but it didn't helped :/

Comment: Then your original code had several errors.  Can you trim your problem down to the simplest thing that doesn't work?

Comment: @TimeToThine There's no reason to be offensive to people who are trying to help you. You posted a huge mess of code and multiple people have told you the **one** thing that was wrong with *the code you posted*.  JavaScript errors elsewhere in the page could be causing your problem, so asking to simplify your code and your problem is not an absurd request.

Comment: @JimSchubert I wasn't rude, but you tell me, if I know which code of line got the problem, I would just fix it ini ? , anyway thanks a lot everyone who is trying to help me :)

Comment: If you want people to help you, you need to make it easy.  You have too much code up there, and yet it's not complete enough to easily reproduce your problem.  That's why everyone has responded with the first thing that's obviously wrong.  As I suggested above, make it smaller.  There are parts that work correctly and aren't relevant, right?  Remove them.  I didn't vote the question down, but this is why people have.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the output in quotes:

```
document.getElementById(<%=btnConfOK.ClientID%>)
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("<%=btnConfOK.ClientID%>")
```

Comment: sorry but it didn't helped :/ either as well

Answer (score 1):

You missing the syntax `document.getElementById("<%=btnConfOK.ClientID%>").focus();`

Read more about [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById)

**Edit**

```
function ShowMessage()
        {
            DisplayConfirmMessage('Do you really want to delete this decision?',480,120);
            document.getElementById("<%=btnConfOK.ClientID%>").focus();
            //SetDefaultButton('btnConfOK');
            return false;
        }
```

If your delete button doing the post-back, use  [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) on delete button click.

Comment: sorry but it didn't helped :/ either

Comment: @TimeToThine: did you change your **function ShowMessage()** with above format??

Comment: Yes i did, but it appears and disappears then

Comment: which is appear and disappear?? **btnConfOK** ??

Comment: The Dialog Box containing "Yes" and "No" buttons

Comment: what about your **DisplayConfirmMessage**.. did you check that?

Comment: More like, Delete button doing postback